# Where can I try sea cucumbers in Taiwan?

Tags: food-and-drink, restaurants, taiwan

Apparently sea cucumbers are quite a delicacy in many Asian countries. I was wondering if anyone knows of good places to try sea cucumber in Taiwan, or if there are good places to purchase them?

Comment: Maybe some places around 'snake alley' if you're looking for that sort of thing.

Comment: There is nothing strange about sea cucumbers. I don't know about Taiwan, but in Singapore you can buy it in any supermarket, and many restaurants will serve it. I've also had it in Chinese restaurants in San Francisco. Definitely not something you need to go to dodgy alleys for.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I've had it (sea slugs) in Toronto as well- it's fairly common (and overrated, in my opinion, except perhaps as an aphrodisiac, where perception matters). The dried/rehydrated variety in particular should be available anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It's not uncommon, so you can buy them in any traditional market. There are, however, the real one and the "fake" one. I will recommend going to a decent restaurant and order a dish with it. Most fancier Chinese restaurants should have it.

Comment: How can one distinguish between the real and fake ones?

Comment: The fake one is a bit harder, and will stay the same after cooking. The real one will be smaller after heating. Also, since the fake one is artificial, the spikes might look more uniform than the real one.

This is a video regarding it. The left one is the fake one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78ux_xUcFP8

Answer (score 2):

You can find sea cucumber in markets near harbor or hotel restaurant. The price is around NT$400/600g in port markets, but it depends on some factors. In hotel restaurant, a set of sea cucumber in Evergreen Hotel is about NT$2000.

I think there are meals of sea cucumber in most 5-star hotel. If you can read Chinese, have a check [on this website](http://www.ipeen.com.tw/search/taiwan/000/0-100-0-0/%E6%B5%B7%E5%8F%83/) for this dish.